# Building TabBar in QML - Loader doesn't show all the Rectangles

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window
{
    visible: true
    height: 500
    width: 500

    property VisualItemModel contentToBeShownOnTabClick : visualItemModelDemo
    property variant tabLabels                    : ["Navigation", "Payload", "System Control"]

    VisualItemModel
    {
        id: visualItemModelDemo

        Rectangle
        {
            id: navigationTab
            color: "green"
            height: 200
            width: 200
        }
        Rectangle
        {
            id: navigationTab1
            color: "darkgreen"
            height: 200
            width: 200
        }
        Rectangle
        {
            id: navigationTab2
            color: "lightgreen"
            height: 200
            width: 200
        }
    }

    MainForm
    {
        Component
        {
            id: tabsOnBottomComponent
            Repeater
            {
                model:   tabLabels
                // The Tabs
                Rectangle
                {
                    id:             tabsOnBottom
                    // This anchoring places the tabs on the outer top of the parent rectangle.
                    anchors.top:    parent.bottom
                    anchors.topMargin: 180
                    color:          "lightsteelblue"
                    border.color:   "steelblue"
                    border.width:   2
                    implicitWidth:  Math.max ((labelTabsBottom.width + 4), 80)
                    implicitHeight: 20
                    radius:         2
                    // Tabs Text/Label
                    Text
                    {
                        id:                 labelTabsBottom
                        anchors.centerIn:   parent
                        color:              "white"
                        rotation:           0
                        // With reference to mode: tabLabels
                        text:               modelData
                        font.pointSize:     11
                    }

                    MouseArea
                    {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked:    bottomTabClicked (index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        Rectangle
        {
            // The things which get displayed on clicking of a tab will be shown in this rectangle.
            id:           areaForTabContents
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 10
            height:       parent.height
            width :       parent.width
            color :       "pink"

            // These are the tabs displayed in one row - horizontally.
            Row
            {
                id:      horizontalTabs

                Loader
                {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    sourceComponent: tabsOnBottomComponent
                }
            }
        }

        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

This gets shown as follows:
[image]

whereas I want it to see 3 rectangles there side by side.

Comment: `Row` derives from `Item`, so `horizontalTabs` will also need to specify `anchors.fill: parent`.

Comment: @cmannett85 If I write `anchors.fill` in the Row, Qml says: `Row: Cannot specify left, right, horizontalCenter, fill or centerIn anchors for items inside Row.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Loader` is not a transparent type w.r.t. the containing type, `Row` in this case. I think this is an issue related to [creation context](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#creation-context) and the way `Repeater` works. From the documentation of the latter:

> Items instantiated by the `Repeater` are inserted, in order, as **children of the `Repeater`'s parent**. The insertion starts immediately after the `Repeater`'s position in its parent stacking list. This allows a `Repeater` to be used inside a layout.

The `Rectangle`s are indeed added to the parent which is the `Loader`, they **stack up** - `Loader` does not provide a positioning policy - then they are added to the `Row` resulting in just one `Item` (the last one) to be visible.

You can tackle the problem with few different approaches, depending on the properties you want to maintain or not. I would get rid of anchoring in the `Component` and move it to the containing `Row`. A too specific anchoring inside a `Component` could be a pain in the neck when it is instanced and used all over a (not so small) project.

As a first approach you can re-parent the `Repeater` to the `Row`, i.e. you can rewrite code as:

```
Row
{
    id: horizontalTabs

    Loader
    {
        sourceComponent: tabsOnBottomComponent
        onLoaded: item.parent = horizontalTabs
    }
}
```

However this would result in warnings due to the `Component` anchoring references not working as expected any more.

If you still want to maintain the anchoring, as defined in the `Component`, and off-load the creation, you can go for the dynamic way (if the semantics fits in your use case), i.e. you can use [`createObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method). This way you totally avoid the `Loader` and the related issue. For instance, you can create the `Repeater` once the `Row` has completed its creation:

```
Row
{
    id: horizontalTabs
    Component.onCompleted: tabsOnBottomComponent.createObject(horizontalTabs)
}
```

Clearly, the creation code can be move anywhere else, depending on your needs.